# Is there a special name for $E[X|Y]=Y$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

As the question suggests, given two random variables $X, Y$, I am wondering if there is a special name for the relation $E[X|Y]=Y$ (we know that $E[X|Y]=f(Y)$ for some measurable function $f$, so another way to ask the question is if there is a name for the special case when $f$ is the identity function).

Context: I am interested in the particular case where $X$ is an indicator function. In that case, $E[X|Y]=P(X|Y)=Y$, which we can understand roughly as saying $Y$ is a good estimator for the probability of $X$ absent further information.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since $E(X\mid Y)$ gives the regression of $X$ on $Y$, you can say that this regression is linear. But that is true even if $E(X\mid Y)=a+bY$ for any $a,b$.